# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory- on upgrading tomcat from version 7 to 9

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat7, tomcat9

I recently upgraded my tomcat to  from v7.3 to v9.43 and all of a sudden my application throws an exception at server startup while connecting to DB. 
Exception LOG: 
SEVERE: Exception processing global JNDI Resources
    javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:70)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:65)
        ... 21 more

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You should add this [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4)

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
```